# Does the term "social enterprise" have a legal meaning?

Tags: contract-law, international, ohio

There is a sector of public opinion that often refers to "social enterprise"
as if the meaning of this term were well-known. Does the public understand
what this term means? Or only specialists? Here is something I just read:

*"Business enterprise, i.e. capitalism, must be measured in terms of monetary profit. That rule is not arguable. A business enterprise must make monetary profit, or it will merely cease to exist. That is an absolute requirement. But it does not follow that this must necessarily be the final bottom line and the sole aim of the enterprise. How this profit is used is another question.*

*It is commonly assumed that profit will enrich enterprise owners and investors, which in turn gives them incentive to participate financially in the enterprise to start with. That, however, is not the only possible outcome for use of profits. Profits can be directly applied to help resolve a broad range of social problems: poverty relief, improving childcare, seeding scientific research for nationwide economic advancement, improving communications infrastructure and accessibility, for examples – the target objectives of this particular project plan.*

*same financial discipline required of any conventional for-profit business can be applied to projects with the primary aim of improving socioeconomic conditions. Profitability provides money needed to be self-sustaining for the purpose of achieving social and economic objectives such as benefit of a nation’s poorest, neediest people. In which case, the enterprise is a social enterprise."*

If this definition is accepted, does a "social enterprise" have a legal meaning.

Is it the same as a "non-profit"? or are their significant differences? Thank you!

Comment: Could you please indicate the source of your quote, ideally by giving title, author, and a link? Also, could you cite 1 or 2 other places you have seen this term used, please? The text quoted seems to be defining the term, and it may be that other sources use it differently.  "Social Enterprise" is not a term I have often seen used.

Comment: This is from "A ‘Marshall Plan’ for Ukraine", http://wp.p-ced.org/projects/ukraine/a-marshall-plan-for-ukraine/.

Comment: "social enterprise" is a term we have been hearing for a long time; I had thought it was a commonplace. I understand that Google Search is unreliable in terms of the number of page references it claims to link to: Still it says "About 14,000,000 results". Even if this were only 4 million, that would still be a lot!

Comment: Why is this tagged for "ohio"?

Comment: @user6726 The questioner is most concerned with the way this question is analyzed in light of Ohio law.

Comment: Also in British Colombia, Canada.

Answer (score 2):

a "for profit business" is one in which profits may be, at lest potentially, distributed to owners, who may be shareholders or partners.

A "non-profit organization" is one in which surpluses (which is what they earn instead of profits), if any, cannot legally be distributed yo any owners or participants. Often there are no "owners", but the organization may have "members". The members may be able to determine organization policies to some degree, and may be able to chose members of a board of directors or other governing body.

A "non-profit organization" need not be organized for any particular purpose, and need not provide something generally recognized as of "social value" or aim at "improving socioeconomic conditions". Such an organization may be sustained by profits on operations, or by donations, or by government funding, or some combination of these.

While members may in some way benefit from the actions or activities of a non-profit, they may not directly share in any profits made.

Churches, charities, and museums are commonly set up as non-profits. So are many universities. So are professional associations such as the American Bar Association (ABA),  the Institute of Electrical and Electronic Engineers (IEEE), or the Association for Computing Machinery (ACM). I myself am a member and have been an officer of the ACM. Recreational organizations such as the American Contract Bridge League (ACBL) and sporting clubs are also non-profits. Labor unions are also typically set up as non-profits. So are social clubs.

In many jurisdictions, some but not all non-profits are partially or totally exempt from taxation.

In my experience the term "social enterprise" is not widely used, nor consistently defined. Some non-profits might be so classified, perhaps others would not. "non-profit" and "tax exempt" are both terms with defined legal meanings and legal consequences. I think that "social enterprise" is more a term to be used in sociology.

Comment: "A social enterprise or social business is defined as a business with specific social objectives that serve its primary purpose. Social enterprises seek to maximize profits while maximizing benefits to society and the environment, and the profits are principally used to fund social programs." This definition characterizes 'social enterprise' as a type of business.

Comment: "The first time I heard the term “social enterprise” was in college. Case study after case study, we examined successful social entrepreneurs who were making a scalable difference in the lives of others. Their impact was made possible thanks to social enterprise’s emphasis on financial sustainability, unlike nonprofits I’d seen fail without enough funding ...I came to love the field so much that I eventually pursued a Master’s Degree in Social Entrepreneurship and even taught the same class at my alma mater years later." https://www.thegoodtrade.com/features/what-is-a-social-enterprise

Comment: @Maria Alaniz Thank you. I suspect this is an economic and social classification, not a legal one.

Comment: "“social enterprise” is a paradigm rather than a legal structure, its understanding is a bit murky, and an entity’s overall impact can be hard to qualify or quantify. Compounded with the fact that “impact” is a long-term goal, social enterprises are challenged about how they can measure such outcomes. Critics often question if these kinds of for-profit ventures are really creating social value—how can we differentiate PR measures and greenwashing from tangible change?"

Comment: IMO It's impossible to correlate the professed Principles of an entity and the Real World.

Answer (score 2):

"Social enterprise" is not a term with a well defined legal meaning (at least in U.S. law).

A similar concept that is legally well defined is a "[benefit corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benefit_corporation)" or a "public benefit corporation", which is a particular type of entity organization (not a functional test) related to how a generically formed entity operates:

> In the United States, a benefit corporation (or in several
> jurisdictions including Delaware, a public-benefit corporation or PBC)
> is a kind of for-profit corporate entity, authorized by 35 U.S. states
> and the District of Columbia, that includes positive impact on
> society, workers, the community and the environment in addition to
> profit as its legally defined goals, in that the definition of "best
> interest of the corporation" is specified to include those impacts.
> Laws concerning conventional corporations (referred to as "C
> corporations" by the IRS) typically do not specify the definition of
> "best interest of the corporation", which has led to the
> interpretation that increasing shareholder value (profits and/or share
> price) is the only overarching or compelling interest of a
> corporation. Benefit corporations may not differ much from traditional
> C corporations. A C corporation may change to a B corporation merely
> by stating in its approved corporate bylaws that it is a benefit
> corporation; however in certain jurisdictions (especially Delaware),
> the terms "public benefit corporation" or "PBC" are also required to
> be in the legal name of B corporations.